# Azure Function - Managed IDs to write to storage table - failing with 403 AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure function application (HTTP trigger) that writes to the storage queue and table.  Both fail when I try to change to managed Id.  This post / question is about just the storage table part.

Here's the code that does the actual writing to the table:

```
        GetStorageAccountConnectionData();
        try
        {
            WorkspaceProvisioningRecord provisioningRecord = new PBIWorkspaceProvisioningRecord();

            provisioningRecord.status = requestType;
            provisioningRecord.requestId = requestId;
            provisioningRecord.workspace = request;
            #if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID"));
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID"));
            DefaultAzureCredentialOptions options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
            {
                Diagnostics =
                {
                    LoggedHeaderNames = { "x-ms-request-id" },
                    LoggedQueryParameters = { "api-version" },
                    IsLoggingContentEnabled = true
                },
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
                ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true

            };

            #endif
    DefaultAzureCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    Console.WriteLine(connection.storageTableUri);
    Console.WriteLine(credential);
    var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(new Uri(connection.storageTableUri), credential);
    var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(connection.tableName);
    await tableClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    var entity = new TableEntity();
    entity.PartitionKey = provisioningRecord.status;
    entity.RowKey = provisioningRecord.requestId;
    entity["requestId"] = provisioningRecord.requestId.ToString();
    entity["status"] = provisioningRecord.status.ToString();
    entity["workspace"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(provisioningRecord.workspace);
    //this is where I get the 403
    await tableClient.UpsertEntityAsync(entity);

 //other stuff...

catch(AuthenticationFailedException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Authentication Failed. {e.Message}");
    WorkspaceResponse response = new PBIWorkspaceResponse();
    response.requestId = null;
    response.status = "failure";
    return response;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"whoops!  Failed to create storage record:{ex.Message}");
    WorkspaceResponse response = new WorkspaceResponse();
    response.requestId = null;
    response.status = "failure";
    return response;
}
```

I have the client id/ client secret for this security principal defined in my local.settings.json as AZURE_TENANT_ID/AZURE_CLIENT_ID/AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET.

The code dies trying to do the upsert. And it never hits the AuthenticationFailedException - just the general exception.

The security principal defined in the AZURE* variables was used to created this entire application including the storage account.

Comment: What kind of permissions does the security principal has on the azure subscription?

Comment: it's an owner at the subscription level.   And then when I go to the resource group and check "Access Control (IAM)" option from there, this same security principal is listed as owner (inherited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage data inside a storage account (like creating table etc.), you will need to assign different sets of permissions. `Owner` role is a control-plane role that enables you to manage storage accounts themselves and not the data inside them.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-blobs):

> Only roles explicitly defined for data access permit a security
> principal to access blob data. **Built-in roles such as Owner,
> Contributor, and Storage Account Contributor permit a security
> principal to manage a storage account, but do not provide access to
> the blob data within that account via Azure AD**.

Even though the text above is for Blobs, same thing applies for Tables as well.

Please assign [`Storage Table Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-contributor) to your Managed Identity and then you should not get this error.